# MonoGame: Cannot load assets

Tags: c#, assets, monogame

I started days ago programming c# using monogame.
Today I got an error that says "Could not load asset as a non-content file".
Here's the code, I need much help.
        List textures;

```
    public Game1()
        : base()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        // the below line errors
        textures.Add(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Lol"));

    }
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

1. Create a sub-folder under the Content one.
2. Call it "Assets"
3. Right click on the image file and right click
4. Properties -> Copy to Output -> Copy always
5. Go to the main class and set the RootDirectory as "Content.RootDirectory = @"Content\Assets";"

P.s. : Everytime you add a file, repeat 3rd and 4th step